# flutter list to nested json manually

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a contact list, where I would like to send the givenName, familyName and displayName to an api using json string..

```
final contacts =
    (await ContactsService.getContacts(withThumbnails: false)).toList();
```

I tried but unable to created nested array:

```
List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();

for (final contact in contacts) {
    list.add(contact.givenName);
}

print(list);
```

I would like it something like:

```
[
    {"id":1,"givenName":"Joe","familyname":"Walker"},
    {"id":2,"givenName":"Zoe","familyname":"Sleeper"}
];
```

Comment: Can you share contacts list which comes from ContactsService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**
try this one

```
for (final contact in contacts) {
     var json = {'givenName' : contact.givenName, 'familyName': contact.familyName};
     list.add(json);
 }
```

**OLD**

Your Contact class should have a toJson method to do this.

```
class Contact {
   Int id;
  String givenName, familyName;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
  {
    'id': id,
    'givenName' : givenName, 
    'familyName': familyName,
  }; 
}
```

Now your code should work

```
List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();

for (final contact in contacts) {
    list.add(contact.toJson());
}

print(list);
```

Comment: I am getting errors is it possible class Contact is conflicts with https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service package as thats also uses Contact ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/andraskende/24a26b98fea68424557bad6f34641ea4 the error message is commented, Thank you !

Comment: try this one
`for (final contact in contacts) {
    var json = {'givenName' : contact.givenName, 'familyName': contact.familyName};
    list.add(json);
}`

Comment: Perfect! Thank You !!